# Create new data based on comparison of columns with min function

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, dplyr

Consider the following data set:

```
  id         T1         T2        C
1  1  2616.4570   1771.046 3949.541
2  1  3240.6843   1771.046 1333.084
3  2 37388.1503  26368.323 3948.928
4  3  8549.1548 143049.845 3959.415
5  4   860.7339  36772.155 3754.725
6  4 18439.1797  36772.155 2893.991
```

I am trying to create a new data set with three columns (T, B1, B2) by T=min(T1,T2, C). By this, I expect to obtain B1 and B2 as follows: when T=T1, B1=1 and B2=0; when T=T2, B1=0 and B2=1; and when T=C, B1=0 and B2=0. I have written the following codes to implement this

```
df %>% 
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(
  B1 = as.numeric(cumsum(T1) < C),
  T = ifelse(B1 == 1, T1, min(T2,C)),
  B2 = ifelse(B1 == 1, 0, ifelse(B1==0 & min(T2,C)==T2,1,0)))%>%
group_by(id, B1) %>%
mutate(n = 1:n()) %>%
ungroup() %>%
filter(B1 == 1 | (B1 == 0 & n == 1)) %>%
dplyr::select(-n, -T1, -T2, -C)
```

and it provides

```
id         T     B1     B2 
 1 2616.4570      1      0  
 1 1333.0844      0      0  
 2 3948.9283      0      0  
 3 3959.4146      0      0  
 4  860.7339      1      0  
 4 2893.9910      0      0
```

However, this reported output is incorrect. For example, for the first row of id 1 from the original data min(T1,T2,C)=T2, so I expect T=T2 (i.e. 1771.046), B1=0 and B2=1, but the reported output shows T=T1 (i.e. 2616.4570), B1=1 and B2=0 which is incorrect. The second row of id 1 is correct. There is something wrong with the code but am finding it difficult to identify this. Any help on this is greatly appreciated! The expected output would look like

```
 id        T1     B1     B2 
 1 1771.046       0      1  
 1 1333.0844      0      0  
 2 3948.9283      0      0  
 3 3959.4146      0      0  
 4  860.7339      1      0  
 4 2893.9910      0      0
```

Comment: Can you please show your expected output for given data?

Comment: @RonakShah thank you! I have reported the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(T = pmin(T1, T2, C, na.rm = TRUE),
         B1 = case_when(T == T1 ~ 1,
                        T == T2 ~ 0,
                        T == C ~ 0,
                        TRUE ~ NA_real_),
         B2 = case_when(T == T1 ~ 0,
                        T == T2 ~ 1,
                        T == C ~ 0,
                        TRUE ~ NA_real_))
     id     T1      T2     C     T    B1    B2
  <int>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2616.   1771. 3950. 1771.     0     1
2     1  3241.   1771. 1333. 1333.     0     0
3     2 37388.  26368. 3949. 3949.     0     0
4     3  8549. 143050. 3959. 3959.     0     0
5     4   861.  36772. 3755.  861.     1     0
6     4 18439.  36772. 2894. 2894.     0     0
```

You can then use your `select` call to get rid of the columns you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a row-wise approach and not grouped by `id`.

Using `apply` in base R.

```
t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {
   T <- min(x)
   ind <- which.min(x)
   if(ind == 1) {B1 = 1;B2 = 0}
   else if(ind == 2) {B1 = 0;B2 = 1}
   else {B1 = 0;B2 = 0}
   c(T = T, B1 = B1, B2 = B2)
}))

#          T B1 B2
#1 1771.0460  0  1
#2 1333.0840  0  0
#3 3948.9280  0  0
#4 3959.4150  0  0
#5  860.7339  1  0
#6 2893.9910  0  0
```